# Identifying image location?

Tags: imagery, satellite

[image]

I have a satellite image of only one part of some city with a lot of vegetation. I need to find out where is that image taken.

Is there any way to find out where it is taken on Google Maps, Google Earth or something similar?

It is a .jpg image so I don't know how to start search.

Comment: [Google Image search](http://images.google.com/webhp) turns up 5 alleged links, all on a German-language wireless technology forum.  So it found the images but it's still unclear where the location is!

Comment: I've protected this question because it risks being used as a precedent for an infinite number of "post an aerial photo or satellite image and tell me where it is" questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [TinyEye](http://www.tineye.com/), a reverse image search. It will take your image and find any instances of it existing elsewhere on the web. This probably isn't the best bet for most satellite imagery, but searching could yield something if you didn't source the image yourself.

Alternatively, you can trying viewing the [image metadata](http://www.mydigitallife.info/view-and-display-date-picture-taken-and-camera-model-metadata-of-photos-in-windows-explorer/), which may tell you something about the date/location of the image.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help. I also tried search with Google by images but it didn't find anything. Is there some software which can search whole satellite imagery of the world by pixels or something?

Comment: Do you know anything about the image you have? Where did it come from? Approximately when it was taken? What is the resolution? What country it was taken in? You'll need to provide more detail.

Comment: Horizontal resolution: 72dpi, vertical resolution: 72dpi. Bit depth: 24. I don't know anything else. So there's no any software?

Comment: As far as I know there is no software available for searching massive amounts of archived satellite/aerial imagery. Where did you get the image from? Can you post it in your question? Maybe someone will recognize it.

Comment: I don't know anything. This is the image down.

Answer (score 11):

### IMAGE REVERSE SEARCH WITH GOOGLE IMAGES

Doing a reverse search using [images.google.com](http://images.google.com) I found this link from wikimedia commons:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:M%C3%BCnchen_Geiselgasteig_Filmstadt_Aerial.jpg

Which states it is a File called "München Geiselgasteig Filmstadt Aerial.jpg"
Which was posted a few later than you question (2012) by http://vermessung.bayern.de/opendata

If you already know of a satelite or street view image reverse lookup, I would appreciate the info.

Recent proyect [TerraPattern](http://www.terrapattern.com/about) seems to do such a job using neural networks, but you need to send them a tweet for them to make the search.

Comment: You are correct, it's that part of town. Just searching for it on OSM proves it, but one could also switch to satellite view if needed: https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=M%C3%BCnchen%20Geiselgasteig%20#map=16/48.0646/11.5487&layers=C

Comment: Great contribution! I noticed the third link is dead, however.