# Finding source map tile

Tags: google-maps, tiles, similarity

Given a degraded image of a Google maps tile, for example:

[image: akademi high]

Is there a service or technique I can use to find the map coordinates of this tile?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a hastily penned question about geography rather than a focused and detailed question about GIS

Comment: It has some kind of mystery around it though.... I wonder what place it is now.

Comment: @PolyGeo I've tried to pull the root issue out of this question.  I think the result is a an interesting question that is on-topic.  It's essentially a map equivalent of this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/17619/18189

Comment: @dbaston I'll re-open

Comment: This place is Uenohara high school near Tokyo in Japan. Got the answer by googling but don't know how to search such fade image's location.

Comment: @GeoSpatialEarth.in - Regardless, I think you should post your comment as an answer with a nice screenshot ;)

Comment: @GeoSpatialEarth.in - can you explain a bit how you "Googled" this?  I tried doing an image search with the degraded image, but the hits weren't relevant.  While knowing the location of this particular image may interest the OP, I think it would be most relevant to see an answer for the general case.

Comment: @dbaston when you do the image search in Google by uploading the image, you will get a Twitter search result.. there I got the answer..  https://twitter.com/bijuumike?lang=en

Comment: @Joseph I am not posting it as an answer because the given picture was just for example.. the real question was asked about the method to find such locations from faded non georeferenced Google map tiles.

Comment: It there a specific reason for this search ? Maybe with some more info we could refine the nanswers or find another way towards your real objective

Answer (score 1):

*(EDIT : I ended up to the same conclusion as in the comments, some of them I hadn't seen before answering. At least there's an answer, even if it doesn't solve your real problem)*

You can use [Google Image service](https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=FR) : By uploading the image to google (the little camera), I found this link (second match) where you can see a similar image : https://twitter.com/MissGrumpyGamer/status/892452360605360129

As another alternative, you can have a look at [Tiny eye](https://www.tineye.com/) as mentionned in this question, very similar to yours : [Identifying image location?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17619/identifying-image-location)

The post also mention [Terra Pattern](http://www.terrapattern.com/about), but I highly doubt it could work on your degraded map tile.

However, **it implies somebody has posted on internet a similar image and that Google looked at it**...

[image: Location searched]